# How can destination view controller be pushed on to the same navigation controller programatically, Swift

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swift3

Searching SO, I figured out that there many questions on navigating to a destinationViewController programatically, but none on how the destinationViewController can be pushed (programatically) on to the same navigation controller from which it got triggered.

**This is what I have (See Picture of Storyboard)**

I have 2 scenes with their respective controllers, appointments (source) and appointmentTimes (destination)

a. Navigation controller is connected to appointments through a segue.

b. appointmentTimes is not connected to appointments through a segue in storyboard (since I would like to navigate to it programatically when a button ('Schedule Appointment') is clicked in appointments scene)

**This is what I want (See Picture of Storyboard)**

a. When a user clicks a button ('Schedule Appointment') in appointments scene (source) // DONE

b. Some requests are made to the server and on obtaining response, the user is navigated programatically to appointmentTimes scene (destination) // DONE

c. I would like the appointmentTimes scene to be pushed onto the same navigation stack as the appointments scene. This means the user can freely navigate between the two scenes (by clicking 'Schedule Appointment' in appointments scene they can go to appointmentTimes scene, and by clicking back button in appointmentTimes scene they can go back to appointments scene) // HOW CAN I ACHIEVE THIS ??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that following steps help to achieve the desired outcome of adding the destination scene on to the same navigation stack of the source scene programatically.

1. Create a manual segue: Go to storyboard, point the mouse on the yellow icon of the source scene (you can find it on top of the scene) and Control + Drag on to the destination scene to create a manual segue.
2. Give the segue an ID, select the segue and go to the attributes and add a name in the identifier cell.
3. Call the segue programatically `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "appointment", sender: nil)`, This will add the destination scene on to the same navigation stack as the source scene.